# How to save data entry to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have an assignment where I have to develop a Windows application using Visual Basic .NET. From the form that I have designed, it should save all records in a table in a MySQL database. How should I do this? Here's what I've got so far:

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class AddMember
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\127.0.0.1"

        con.Open()

        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO memberdetails (ID, Name, Surname, Age, Gender, Contact, Address) VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Surname, @Age, @Gender, @Contact, @Address)"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", TextBox3.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", TextBox4.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ComboBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", TextBox6.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox7.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        con.Close()

        MsgBox("Added Successfully")
    End Sub
End Class
```

**con.Open()-error 26**

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your connection string. try this connection string format:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"
```

and since your database server is `MySQL`, you shouldn't use `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace but instead use `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` namespace.